# internet explorer downloading when we submit form in springPortlet

Tags: spring-mvc, internet-explorer, spring-portlet-mvc

For one of my liferay portlet screens when i submit form internet explorer is downloading JSON insted of submitting the form. It is working fine in other browsers.

When i have checked in the developer tools in chrome and IE for IE the content-type is

```
"multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7e0119371029c"
```

For chrome it is

```
`"application/json;charset=UTF-8"`
```

I have googled and tried to add content type in the action class annotations as below but it did not work.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="view",  consumes="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

and i was unable to use the below code as it has been has been deprecated according to http://spring.io/blog/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements/

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pets", headers="Content-Type=application/json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the json as `text/html` or `text/x-json` since IE does not know what to do with application/json contents.

Instead of this

```
      @RequestMapping(value="view",  consumes="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

Use this one if it helps

```
      @RequestMapping(value="view",  consumes="text/html;charset=UTF-8")
```

Try this one also if it helps

```
      @RequestMapping(value="view",  consumes="text/x-json;charset=UTF-8")
```

Comment: Did you  check in the developer tools in IE  what is the content-type coming after changing. 
Please post some code snippet also in your question for more accurate analysis.

Comment: it is same "multipart/form-data; " in IE